# Remove thousands separator from a line starting with Total Value

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file which was generated with Powershell.
There is a line that starts with Total Value: $
That line has a dollar amount which contains a thousands separator comma.
I would like to delete that comma, but only in that line.
I have tried using the following however it removes commas where I was not wanting this to
occur.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\User\Summary.txt"
foreach ($file in $Files)
    {
        $file |
        Get-Content | 
        % {$_ -replace '([\d]),([\d])','$1$2' } | 
        out-file "C:\Users\User\Summary2.csv" -append -encoding ascii
    }
```

This works however again it is removing comma in areas of the file which I was hoping they could remain.
Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide examples from the original file, the expected outcome, and the current outcome. Currently your question is quite confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
foreach ($file in $Files)
{
    (Get-Content $file -Raw) -replace '(?m)(?<=^Total\s+Value:\s*\$[\d,]*),','' |
    out-file "C:\Users\User\Summary2.csv" -append -encoding ascii
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g7tdEi/1).

*Details*:

- `Get-Content $file -Raw` gets the contents of the file into a single string variable
- `(?m)(?<=^Total\s+Value:\s*\$[\d,]*),` is a regex that matches

  - `(?m)`
  - `(?<=^Total\s+Value:\s*\$[\d,]*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

    - `^` - start of a line
    - `Total\s+Value:` - `Total Value:` string with any one or more whitespaces between the two words
    - `\$[\d,]*` - a `$` char and then zero or more digits or commas (a dollar price integer part)
  - `,` - a comma (that will be removed since the `-replace` operator is used with an empty replacement pattern (that can even be removed))